# Bug: Adding enumeration value does not update the canvas anymore

Tags: codefluent

There is a bug in the current version of codefluent. When you add a new enumeration value to an enumeration you don't see the value on the canvas. The XML file is updated however. Only closing the canvas and reopening it will show the new enumeration value.

Update:
Seemed to be a bug in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 RC3.

Comment: How do you add it?

Comment: Right click > Add enumeration value. But now I tried it again, it works fine. Have seen it several times before however. Next time i'll make a video...

Comment: Witnessed it again several times on my laptop. Upgrading from Visual Studio 2015 update 3 RC3 to stable solved the problem.

Comment: Probably due to 3rd party (including Microsoft's ones) in Visual Studio. You should answer your self and mark it as the answer.